# Displaying only one element that belongs to a class that is used by many elements

Tags: jquery, css

Having trouble showing only the submenu closest to the category that is hovered by the user. When a users hover over any category, all submenus appear.

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".category").hover(function(){
            $(".submenu").show();
        });
    });

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li><a class="category" href="#">Cars </a>
            <ul class="submenu" style="position:absolute; display:none;">
                <li><a href="#">Ford</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chevy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VW</a></li>  
            </ul>      
        </li>   
        <li><a class="category" href="#">Food </a>
            <ul class="submenu" style="position:absolute; display:none;">      
                <li>Fruits</li>      
                <li>Burgers</li>         
                <li>Veggies</li>     
            </ul> 
        </li>
    </ul> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".submenu").show();` will find ALL elements matching the selector. You need to find the element relative to the CLICKED item which will be `$(this)`.

Try:

```
 $(".category").hover(function(){
      $(this).next('ul').show();
 });
```

or

```
 $(".category").hover(function(){
      $(this).next('.submenu').show();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

closest() looks up the html tree, you want to use find() to look inside the element behing hovered but you would also want to use the second callback of hover() to hide it again

EDIT it seems you removed closest() from your code

```
$(".category").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".submenu").show();
    },function(){
        $(this).find(".submenu").hide();
    } );
```